# MCU's multiple input power

Tags: microcontroller, power-supply

Why do MCUs have multiple power rails going into it?

---

[image]

<sup>Original image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGAa3.jpg</sup>

---

[image]

<sup>Original image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UHjP.jpg</sup>

Answer (score 3):

MCUs, microprocessors, FPGAs and more have had multiple power rails for *decades*. The reasons are many.

Core power, I/O power (even I/O *bank* power for FPGAs and different I/O standards can require different power), analog power (for ADCs, DACs and even integrated amplifiers) can often be different internally.

That is just a sampling of some of the things we typically incorporate in modern devices.

When the power rails are different, you need to check if any *sequencing* is required (if it is, there are dedicated power sequencers available).

That said, many devices happily run with just one supply but each of those domains needs a power feed.

This is not the same as requiring many pins for a given power rail (I have seen this run to hundreds of pins on large devices) and is due to the current handling capability of each pin (and the inductive effects of the internal bonding).

Answer (score 2):

**Why multiple voltages**

Different parts of the chip may run at different voltages. The core may run on 1-1.8V to use less power. Supplying the IOs from another voltage means you don't have to do your entire design at the core voltage, which would be inconvenient. If the chip uses multiple IO standards (LVDS, CMOS...) this may also need several power supplies. If your chip is a SOC with a RAM die stacked on top of a CPU, the two will probably use different supplies. If your chip has USB, then it may have a separate pin for USB VBUS, etc.

High performance high density silicon is expensive and not necessarily well suited for analog, and implementing a LDO inside the chip would use a lot of area just to make one MOSFET for the pass transistor. Thus voltage regulation is done externally, with a separate chip, which also leaves more options for the designer.

**Why multiple rails at the same voltage**

Some parts of the chip make a lot of noise (core, IO) and others need a clean supply (PLL, ADC, DAC, analog comparator...). It makes sense to use separate rails, with their own private decoupling caps, filters, or even LDOs. This also applies to ground.

Sometimes you want to power down the whole chip except a small part that uses very low power, like a real time clock or SRAM. This often has its separate power pin for a backup supply like a coin cell or supercapacitor.

**Why multiple pins for the same rail**

This is to lower impedance of supply and ground. It's mostly about inductance. On large high performance chips there can be hundreds of supply pins, with a corresponding amount of decoupling capacitors. For example a PC CPU can use a hundred amps at around 1V, so that isn't going through just one pin. Also when high speed signaling is involved, all the current that is output through the IOs has to return to the chip, and it will emit a lot less electromagnetic fields if the return path is close to the IO path. Therefore, supply and ground pins are sprinkled everywhere near IO pins.

Comment: love your answer, just for my knowledge so the different parts that require different voltage are Core,IO,USB ,i guess a better question is where can i find the different parts of a particular MCU that require different voltage ,i'm guessing the datasheet?

Comment: Yes, each chip is different, always check the datasheet

Answer (score 1):

> Why do MCUs have multiple power rails going into it?

Depends on the rail, if it's an I/O rail different voltage levels allow attaching different devices with different voltages.

As far as the MCU core, the core runs at a lower voltage to save on power.